# URL search in same tab using google chorme with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, tabs

I want to screen a lot of websites quickly using VBA. I have to have a quick look at them myself, so I basically just need my code to search for a new URL every other second in the same tab.

The existing VBA code I use is:

```
Sub test

End = Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown).Row
    Dim chromepath As String
    chromepath = """chrome.exe"""
    Dim Weburl As String
    Dim I As Integer
    
For I = 2 To end
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Weburl = Cells(I, 1).Value & """"
    Shell (chromepath & " -url " & Cells(I, 1))
end sub
```

The issue I am having is that it opens a lot of tabs, instead of searching in the same tab every other second. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: `call sendkeys("^w", true)` will close the tab

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your response. It doens't seem to do the trick for me - i just keeps opening new tabs...